# Не работает import wx хотя wxPython установлен

Tags: python, pip, wxpython

Столкнулся с проблемой, при попытке импортировать в проект библиотеку wx командой `import wx` PyCharm выдает следующую ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

Версия Python 3.10.9, дополнительно установленные библиотеки:

1. numpy 1.24.1;
2. Pillow 9.4.0;
3. six 1.16.0;
4. wxPython 4.2.0.

Операционная система Windows 10.

Установку проводил командой:

```sh
pip3 install wxPython
```

При попытке вызвать в cmd еще раз установку пишет следующее:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wxPython in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (9.4.0)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.24.1)

Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from wxPython) (1.16.0)
```

Comment: Используете виртуальное окружение?

Comment: Нет не используется. На всякий случай проверил, выполнив команду: pip uninstall virtualenv и получил вот такой ответ: Skipping virtualenv as it is not installed.

Comment: Ну вы пытаетесь удалить стандартный модуль, это не возможно) Вопрос не в том, установлен virtualenv или нет, а настроил ли, например PyCharm сам виртуальное окружение при создании проекта. Смотрите в настройках проекта Project Interpreter, куда указывает путь к нему, проверяете, тот ли это интерпретатор, который вы запускаете в терминале.

Comment: Хотя нет, virtualenv как раз не стандартный модуль, но в принципе нечего не мешает виртуальному окружению быть созданным через стандартный модуль venv.

Comment: Все, благодаря Вам разобрался. Действительно я совсем забыл, что в PyСharm в File -> Settings -> Project: pythonProject в разделе Python Interpreter должны стоять библиотеки для того проекта над которым сейчас работаешь. А wxPython я установил в стандартную директорию с python, а не туда, где у меня проект сейчас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос разрешился. Подсказал insolor в комментариях.
Действительно я совсем забыл, что в PyСharm в File -> Settings -> Project: pythonProject в разделе Python Interpreter должны стоять библиотеки для того проекта над которым сейчас работаешь. А wxPython я установил в стандартную директорию с python, а не туда, где у меня проект сейчас.